# How to supply class instance as a parameter to Kotlin Function

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello I am new to Kotlin, I wanna know how am I supposed to provide class Instance parameter to Kotlin Function

This is my Java code

```
Auth_REST_API_Client.GET("URL", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable throwable, JSONObject errorResponse) {
                
            }

        });
```

Now in kotlin there's no `new` keyword, so how do I supply `new JsonHttpRepsonseHandler()` to kotlin function

kotlin function is:

```
Auth_REST_API_Client.GET(
            "URL",
            null,
            JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            }
        )
```

getting error at `JsonHttpResponseHandler()`

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions

Comment: @IR42, can you please answer this specific question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create an object of an anonymous class that inherits from some type (or types), use [`object`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions) keyword:

```
Auth_REST_API_Client.GET("URL", null, object : JsonHttpResponseHandler {

    override fun onSuccess(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>, response: JSONObject) {

    }

    override fun onFailure(statusCode: Int, headers: Array<Header>, throwable: Throwable, response: JSONObject) {

    }

})
```